# Magento Composer Installer - Require works, Suggest does not

Tags: composer

So I'm currently playing about with Composer and Magento, and having a bit of trouble getting the `magento-composer-installer` to play nice.

Firstly, my composer.json files!

Module:

```
{
    "name":"namespace/module",
    "description":"Desc",
    "type": "magento-module",
    "suggest":{
        "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    },
    "extra":{
        "map":[
            [
                "app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml",
                "app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml"
            ],
            [
                "app/code/community/Namespace/Module/",
                "app/code/community/Namespace/Module/"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Project:

```
{
    "require": {
        "magento/core":"1.9.1.0",
        "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer": "*",
        "namespace/module":"dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.firegento.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "/home/luker/namespace/module"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-root-dir":"./",
        "magento-deploystrategy":"copy",
        "magento-force": true,
        "magento-deploy-sort-priority": {
            "namespace/module": "200"
        }
    }
}
```

This setup does not work.

However, if I change the module to "**require**" `magento-composer-installer` instead of "**suggest**" it, then it works and gets copied into the code base correctly.

After reading the [docs](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md), I know this is not the correct thing to do.

What have I missed?

(To be honest, not entirely sure what I'm achieving with my `magento-force` and priority extras. I've just been hacking about)

Thanks

Comment: Take care that the Hackathon installer [redirects](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer#important) to an new [repo](https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer) due to the [split](https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer/blob/3.0/doc/FAQ.md#there-was-some-part-about-installing-magento-core-some-time-ago) between the core and module installer.

Comment: Yeah this was posted ages ago, before the split I believe. And I'm not a fan with the direction the `3.0` series is taking, have voiced my opinions here https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer/issues/3#issuecomment-86441461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the suggest is the right choice, at least in theory. Because there are a lot of different installers out there today, and it should be easy to switch or even use none of them, this would not work, if modules all require the installer, or even different installers.

The problem is, that if you install both together, there are cases where the installer is not installed at first, which causes other modules to not get deployed.

this is fixed in the current alpha of version 3, but it needs more testers to find problems caused by the big refactoring.

You now have a few different ways to solve this problem.

- Use require, even if it is not best practice
- use one of the other installers, the AOE one for example is suggested by a lot of people
- use the version 3 of the installer, even if it is still in alpha state

Comment: Neato! That's kind of what I was expecting. You can see I was trying to force some sort of priority in the project composer.json. What should I `require` to get the alpha version 3?

Comment: on http://packages.firegento.com/#!/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer you can see all the available version.
"3.0.0-alpha.2" is the most current release, but "3.0@alpha" or "~3.0@alpha" should also work.
also look into https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-are-unbound-version-constraints-a-bad-idea.md and https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions

Comment: Awesome! I'll try this later on and get back to you :)